# Regex.Unescape exception

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

The following folder path stored on a database table as `\\SnowAngel\IcedData`. However when reading from the database it is coming as:
`string myFolderName = "\\\\SnowAngel\\IcedData";`  Where SnowAngel is the server name.

`Regex.Unescape(myFolderName);`

The above line throws the following exception:

> {"parsing \"\\SnowAngel\IcedData\" - Unrecognized escape sequence \I."}

What I'm missing here ?

Comment: @Riv I see myFolderName as "\\\\SnowAngel\\IcedData"

Comment: Are you seeing it when you are debugging? If you are, then it's just how Visual Studio displays strings. It should have no impact on the actual value of your string

Comment: @Rev you are absolutely right. I have displayed it in a message box, the path looks fine. But why VS is displaying it this way. To confuse developers ? :)

Answer (score 0):

One has to deal with two parsers, the first is the C# language and the second is the regex parser. You have added multiple slashes to speak to the C# parser and that is confusing to the regex parser.

I recommend that you use the C# literal `@` when dealing with regex patterns. That way one doesn't have to worry about the C# parser. Simply change it to

`string myFolderName = @"\\SnowAngel\IcedData";`

and work with it in regex, though that doesn't look like a pattern.